# WCF Streaming Service that returns Stream Length and includes Input Parameters

Tags: .net, wcf

I am trying to create a WCF Streaming Service.  I have two requirements that I seem to be stumbling over trying to get this to work:

- Length of stream size
- Input parameters

My message contract looks like this:

```
[MessageContract]
public class MyStream
{
 [MessageHeader]
 public long StreamSize;

 [MessageBodyMember]
 public Stream StreamData;
}
```

My operation contract looks like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IStreamService
{
     [OperationContract]
     MyStream GetData(string data);
}
```

The error message I receive when trying to use the web service is this:

> The operation 'GetData' could not be
>   loaded because it has a parameter or
>   return type of type
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message
>   or a type that has
>   MessageContractAttribute and other
>   parameters of different types. When
>   using
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message
>   or types with
>   MessageContractAttribute, the method
>   must not use any other types of
>   parameters.

From my understanding of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521429/wcf-stream-length), I need to use a message contract to get the length of my stream, but when I switch from a data contract to a message contract I am no longer allowed to pass in input parameters.

Is there a configuration change I'm missing?  Or something else I can try?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have to create MessageContract for request.

```
[MessageContract]
public class GetDataRequest
{
  [MessageBodyMember(Name="data")]
  public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

Then you define your operation as follows:

```
[OperationContract]
MyStream GetData(GetDataRequest request);
```

Comment: Wow - how simple!  Thanks so much.

Comment: The point is that if you use a message contact for response you also have to use it for request and vice-versa.